Git apply: how to ignore changes marked as "Binary files ... differ"?
I'm storing lots of deb's and rpm's as diffs from a few selected "seed" packages. The diffs are generated using git diff and applied using git apply. I only need the source files in the packages. How can I avoid the git apply error saying cannot apply binary patch to bin/busybox without full index line for chunks like the one below ?
diff --git a/bin/busybox b/bin/busybox
deleted file mode 100755
index bfb3212..0000000
Binary files a/bin/busybox and /dev/null differ

edit: this seems to run fast enough:
gawk '/^diff /         { printf("%s", s); s = $0 "\n"; next }
      /^Binary files / { s=""; next }
                       { s=s $0 "\n" }
      END              { print(s) }'


Once you've added something to the repository, git will always track changes to it. Does your workflow work if you don't add binaries to the repository in the first place?

--exclude and --include can help to apply the diff of the specific files only. You could also exclude or include certain files on git diff.
